# Convert European price to another format

Tags: javascript, converters

I'm trying to convert several European price formats to other formats. The European format is like this:

`€1.795,00`

I need to convert it to

`€1,795.00`

I'm using this script http://josscrowcroft.github.io/money.js/ to convert currencies from one to another. However when when it reads something like `€1.795,00`, it thinks its `€1.79` which is problematic.

Is there a method which would convert any decimals to dots and vice versa? Or is there some other alternative method to achieve what I need.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a cleaner solution but this is the easy one:

```
str.replace(",",";");
str.replace(".",",");
str.replace(";",".");
```

Comment: You have to assign the result of "str.replace" somewhere.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he can understand that

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "€1.795,00";
str = str.replace(",",";").replace(".",",").replace(";",".");
```

Now, str = "€1,795.00";

```
str = str.replace(",",";").replace(".",",").replace(";",".");
```

Now, str = "€1.795,00";

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply everyone, actually I found the solution I was looking for. Here, for anyone else looking for the answer to this.

I'm using money.js as mentioned above to convert currencies and it so happens another script called accounting.js is also necessary if you want to format currencies.

http://josscrowcroft.github.io/accounting.js/

If you have something like `€1.700,00`, use method `accounting.unformat` from accounting.js and you'll get this `1700`

Then simply convert it with money.js   :)

btw, the function explanation is near the bottom of the link